# Grease Pencil - broken lines that should be smooth

Tags: grease-pencil

When I use the grease pencil, I get broken, jagged / pixellated lines that should be smooth.

[image: screenshot attached]

See the "chinks" / breaks in the black line above.

When I zoom in, (here on the bottom left) the pixellation smooths out, though it doesn't disappear:

[image: screenshot 2]

I'm using the latest build of Blender (2.78, 2016-09-15), and the strokes are made with the "Basic Brush".

Would appreciate feedback bout what's going on and how to fix it - 
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your problem is related to a GPU / Driver issue.  I am seeing the same thing you are seeing on a Mac with an ATI graphics card.  If I save my blend file and open it on a different Mac with an Nvidia graphics card the lines are no longer jagged / pixelated.  Check out this link for more information:  [Weird artifacts with Grease Pencil V2](https://developer.blender.org/T49018)

I have not yet found a work-around for this problem, other than to render the final image/sequence on a computer with an Nvidia card.

Comment: Many thanks - 
Had not been able to work this out. Appreciate the feedback.